# Existence of $c \in [a,b]$ Such That $\int_{c-a}^{b-c}f(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

> If $f:[a,b]\to R$ is a continuous function, prove that there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $\int_{c-a}^{b-c}f(x)dx=0$.

Comment: @lulu $b + a - 2c$

Comment: @KennyLau  Right.  Shouldn't try hard things like the distributive law on New Year's morning.  I'll delete my comment now, and this one in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f:[3/4,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, for every $c\in[3/4,1]$, $c-a=c-3/4\leq 1/4$ and is not in the domain.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that $b-c$ is also not in the domain

Comment: But indeed $c=(a+b)/2$ works every time if you consider it defined